# Can someone delete, make a synonym or at least spelling correct the tag standford-core-nlp?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

In December 2013, someone created the tag [standford-core-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standford-core-nlp). It currently has 18 questions, only 7 of which have answers.

This tag should either be deleted (migrating questions to tag [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp)) or made a synonym for [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp), or at least have its spelling corrected: "standford" is a misspelling of "stanford".

The topic of [standford-core-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standford-core-nlp) is a subset of what is covered by [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp). The reasons for suggesting deletion or making a synonym are: [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp) is already a highly specialist, low-volume tag, and so it doesn't make much sense to have an even finer subcategory; many of the questions in [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp) are already about Stanford CoreNLP - many more than in [standford-core-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standford-core-nlp); and (whether for spelling or specialization reasons) [standford-core-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standford-core-nlp) doesn't have a robust community of question answerers.

Could someone take this on? Since I don't have any points on the [standford-core-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standford-core-nlp) tag, I can't do anything. But I am the most active contributor to the [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp) tag.

Comment: Feel free to retagged the questions with available tag first (perhaps [tag:stanford-nlp]). The tag will be automatically deleted on next day if there are no questions tagged with.