# What's the difference between [stanford-nlp] and [corenlp]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

As far as I know both [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp) (2k+) and [corenlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corenlp) (162) refer to the Natural Language Processing framework developed by the Stanford University.

On [their FAQ](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml#Questions), they suggest to use [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp) when asking questions on Stack Overflow. Can the two tags be merged?

Comment: "Let's get at the [corenlp] of the [stanford-nlp] issue"

Comment: The synonym had already been created by the community, so I'm marking this as complete.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm the lead person behind Stanford NLP software releases. I am in favor of treating `corenlp` as a synonym of `stanford-nlp`.

Strictly, they are not the same. `stanford-nlp` refers to a group, rather than a piece of software, and we have other pieces of software, such as GloVe and Phrasal which are not part of Stanford CoreNLP, and we also distribute subparts of Stanford CoreNLP, such as the Stanford Parser and Stanford NER separately (partly for historical reasons, partly because some people like a smaller tool for the task that they actually need).

However, in practice, the volume under the `stanford-nlp` tag is not that high, and 90+% of the questions refer to Stanford CoreNLP or at least things that are part of Stanford CoreNLP, so I think merging is the best course.

At any rate, I don't think any of the developers have been tracking the `corenlp` tag....

Comment: Oh, and I just remembered that a couple of years back there was another round of the same thing, which led to merging `standford-core-nlp` [sic] into `stanford-nlp`; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285116/can-someone-delete-make-a-synonym-or-at-least-spelling-correct-the-tag-standfor

Comment: All you need to do is get some people in the [standford-nlp] tag to [vote for the synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stanford-nlp/synonyms)